# How to sort elasticsearch by multiple fields while comparing the values of those fields to each other?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Let's say I have three objects

```
[
    {
        'name' : 'Apple',
        'popularityFoo': 100,
        'popularityBar': 80,
        'popularity': 40,
    },
    {
        'name' : 'Banana',
        'popularityFoo': 50,
        'popularityBar': 90,
        'popularity': 50,
    },
    {
        'name' : 'Cherry',
        'popularityFoo': 60,
        'popularityBar': 60,
        'popularity': 60,
    }  
];
```

My default sorting is by popularity, returning `Cherry (60), Banana (50), Apple (40)`
If a user has a preferred category it will sort first by that category popularity index and then fall back to popularity. So if my favorite category is Foo it returns `Apple (100), Cherry (60), Banana (50)` and for category  Bar the search returns `Banana (90), Apple (80), Cherry (60)`

Now my question: If my user likes **both** Foo and Bar how can I compare the different popularity values with each other when sorting so I can get the result `Apple (100), Banana (90), Cherry (60)`? Am I indexing wrong? Should I approach this differently?

I have 20 categories and my users have 1-3 favorite categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Mohammad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48677423/81785) for the hint, the way I solved this is using `Math.max(double a, double b)` nesting the function for each additional category.

```
"sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": "Math.max(doc['popularityFoo'].value, Math.max(doc['popularityBar'].value, doc['popularityBaz'].value))",
        "type": "number",
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use script for conditional sorting as following:

```
{
    "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "type" : "number",
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "inline": "doc['popularityFoo'].value > doc['popularityBar'].value ? doc['popularityFoo'].value : doc['popularityBar'].value"
            },
            "order" : "desc"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find the answer!